# Differing responses to jquery.get in firefox vs chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pull JSON data from another source by using the jquery.get method. Unfortunaltey, Firfox 4 and Chrome are giving me different responses. In Firefox I get a string which needs to be parsed, in chrome, I get parsed JSON. Why the difference and how do I avoid it?

```
//works in Firefox
$.get(url, query, function(resp){
    var data = $.parseJSON(resp)
    var hits = data.hits.hits
}

//works in Chrome
$.get(url, query, function(resp){
    var hits = resp.hits.hits
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be better to be explicit: tell jQuery that you're expecting JSON to be returned. This should ensure consistent behaviour.

```
$.get(url, query, function(resp){
    var hits = resp.hits.hits
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Are you sure about your syntax? I don't think there are too many ")" symbols

Comment: @ocoutts Two open brackets, two close brackets, one open curly brace, one close curly brace. Looks right to me...

Comment: @ocoutts So it was. I clearly have vision problems. @Neal Thanks!